# What happens to a VM when you delete it?

Tags: virtualization, data-recovery

I was curious what happens when you select "delete all files" option in Virtualbox? Are files saved on the installed OS in Virtualbox recoverable on your hard drive? Is there a secure way I can delete or hide data that is or was on a VM?

Comment: Assuming a simple VM setup with one virtual disk, all files that are in the VM will be stored on the virtual disk. The virtual disk is just a file. Search for questions about secure erase on your platform (windows? mac?) and secure erase that file. Note that this won't get rid of all traces of the VM, certain configuration settings and info are not stored in the virtual disk and if you shared any folders from the host machine to the VM they will continue to exist on the host.

Comment: I felt like I was just saying "go search for secure erase" and that didn't feel appropriate as an answer to me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Owen for providing an answer to this question!

Assuming a simple VM setup is being used with one virtual disk, all files are stored on the virtual disk which is a file. Using a secure erase feature with your desired erase or "wipe method" to that file, on your platform  should do the trick. Note that this will not get rid of all traces of the VM. Certain configuration settings and info are not stored in the virtual disk and if you added any shared folders from the host machine to the VM they will continue to exist on the host machine.